# Shopify selectCallback function

Tags: javascript, select, callback, shopify

I am having an issue with [my shop](https://gaziano-girling.myshopify.com/) when I try to show two prices for a product, one with UK VAT (20%) and one without. I have followed [the guide](http://support.shopify.com/customer/portal/articles/663599-how-to-show-one-price-with-vat-and-one-price-without-vat) and both prices now show in all sections of my shop but the issues is with items of multiple sizes / colours.

I have bags which are single sizes and these are all correct but when I view any of the shoe or belt items which have multiple sizing and fittings it doesn't calculate for the additional tax.

Shopify have told me "You will need to add JavaScript to your selectCallback function to update both prices, with and without VAT."

I have seen another shop which stocks shoes which seems to have found it possible: http://www.afinepairofshoes.co.uk/collections/featured-products/products/sanders-alfie-brogue-in-teak-brown

Shop: https://gaziano-girling.myshopify.com/
Pass: schura

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In the Responsive theme, the selectCallback function is located in this file: http://www.shopify.com/admin/themes/current#snippets/product-form.liquid.

The SelectCallback function is, like the name suggests, a 'callback' function. In a Shopify theme, this particular function, selectCallback, gets called when the product page is loaded and whenever a shopper picks a variant on the product page. For example, when the shopper picks Small in the Size drop-down and Blue in the Color drop-down, the selectCallback function is called.

That function does various things: it updates the price shown on the page to be the one of the selected product variant, it updates the compare at price too, it also disables the add to cart button if the selected variant is out of stock and then shows some text to alert the shopper 'hey buddy, that one is out of stock, pick another size..'.

In your situation, you need to update 2 more prices on the product page within that function, the price with VAT and the compare at price with VAT.

The rest is JavaScript...